# Place component on specific coordinates of a parent component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I'm trying to create a 'canvas' of some sorts with componenets (people images) spread on various coordinates of the canvas.

Using onLayout I got exact coordinates of the 'canvas' and can calculate from that the desired position for child components.

Is there a way to place children components on those specific coordinates somehow? Maybe important to mention is that the child components are Animated.Views and they are draggable, but that's all good and working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving this is setting `position` property of child components to `absolute`. Then you can use `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` properties to put children to specific coordinates.

Also, you need to set `position` property of the `parent` component to `relative`.

Comment: Thanks, I know about that. It's the best answer so far, but I wanted to know if it's possible to place using coorindates, not absolute positioning, since it depends on the component hierarchy, parents, other positioning, etc.